# Angular - Custom schematics - Create a whole project with a library

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

everything is in the title ! But here's more details.
I'm currently developing a schematics which will create a complete angular project including a library.

I'm using externalSchematic to do it:

```
const rule: Rule = chain([
  externalSchematic('@schematics/angular', 'ng-new', workspaceOptions),
  externalSchematic('@schematics/angular', 'library', libraryOptions),
  sourceParametrizedTemplates
]);
```

However, I get an error message when I try to create the library:

> Message:
> Error: Unable to determine format for workspace path.   Stack:
> Error: Unable to determine format for workspace path.
> at Object.readWorkspace (C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Dev\FWK_INDUS\sources\Angular\FWK.WEB.Schematics\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\core.js:84:15)
> at async Object.getWorkspace (C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Dev\FWK_INDUS\sources\Angular\FWK.WEB.Schematics\node_modules@schematics\angular\utility\workspace.js:51:27)
> at async C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Dev\FWK_INDUS\sources\Angular\FWK.WEB.Schematics\node_modules@schematics\angular\library\index.js:147:27

I assume that I'm creating a new project in a directory and when I try to add the library I'm not inside the directory so schematic is unable to find an angular workspace.

So I'm trying to find a way to specify the path of the new project that I've just created...

If someone know how to do this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case I was running in debug mode (using the 'schematics' command), if that is your case, what is happening is that the default value for the 'project' parameter is not being passed to the schematics program, this parameter is automatically resolved when you are generating your schematic from the ng command, since the ng command takes it from the angular.json file itself.

The quick solution in my case was to use the '--path' parameter at debug (coding) time to specify where I want to apply the schematic, since the parameter 'path' is preferred over the 'project' one it just works.

Comment: Hi Will, I'd like to ask what value did you add as a path param? Just as a ref.. I can't seem to make it work no matter..